# Why there is difference between prediction of SVM model for the same data when ran locally on my machine and on AWS sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, svm, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy sklearn SVM model on AWS SageMaker. But while testing the model, I am getting different outputs even if I am using same `hyperparameters` for algorithm, same training and testing data.

```
svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',gamma=1.0,C=10,probability=True)
```

I am expecting five classes in the output. The following is the output of test data that I got when ran locally:

[image: output of local python script]

In SageMaker, I am only getting four as output for all test data.

Comment: Welcome! Someone will edit your question to embed the image shortly. I'm no expert in this area, but It would probably be helpful to those who know if we could see the specifics of the output on Sagemaker. Thanks! <3

Comment: Thanks :-) I have not added image for sagemaker output because i am only getting Segment = "4" for all 269 test data rows. There is no record/row with segments 0,1,2 or 3 in sagemaker output but we can see all of them(in image) when I tried to predict on my local machine. I am unable to understand reason behind this difference.

Comment: Can you get answers other than 4 by messing with the settings? That seems like it might be an important detail.

Comment: Yes, when i tried svm.SVC(kernel='sigmoid',gamma=1.0,C=10,probability=True) i.e. using kernel='sigmoid' on Sagemaker, it gave 0 (for 52 records), 3(for 2 records) and 4(for 215 records). But this is also different than the output of same algorithm when ran locally  i.e. 0(1), 2(1) and 4(267)

Comment: Hi Praveen,

Are you running the code on SageMaker Notebook Instance? 
If yes then could you share the version of sklearn you are using on your local machine and on the SageMaker Notebook Instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, scikit-learn 0.19.1 on both local and sagemaker notebooks. Sorry for late response.

Comment: The problem is solved, there was some issue with label encoding. Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried setting the same random seed everywhere?

Try using `np.random.seed(0)` at the begin of your code before instantiating the SVM

If that doesn't work, try adding a random state to your model

```
svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',gamma=1.0,C=10,probability=True, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for help :-)     Yes, I have tried both np.random.seed(0) and random_state=0 but there is no change in the output. I am still getting only "4" for all test data(269 records) from deployed model.